# Google Data Studio - How to consolidate duplicates in a column inside a pivot table

Tags: csv, pivot-table, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a Data Studio report, and I'm nearing completion. But getting stuck on this one part.

This is my CSV data, housed in Google Sheets and being imported into Data Studio.

```
Group               ID        Name          Email                 Access
Accounting Dept     932014    Betty Smith   BSmith@example.com    APP 1
Accounting Dept     932014    Betty Smith   BSmith@example.com    APP 2
Accounting Dept     932014    Betty Smith   BSmith@example.com    APP 3
Accounting Dept     321312    Ryan Smith    RSmith@example.com    APP 1
Accounting Dept     321312    Ryan Smith    RSmith@example.com    APP 2
Accounting Dept     321312    Ryan Smith    RSmith@example.com    APP 3
Accounting Dept     543534    John Smith    JSmith@example.com    APP 1
Accounting Dept     543534    John Smith    JSmith@example.com    APP 2
Accounting Dept     543534    John Smith    JSmith@example.com    APP 3
Finance Dept        473924    Sam Smith     SSmith@example.com    App 1
Finance Dept        473924    Sam Smith     SSmith@example.com    App 4
Finance Dept        473924    Sam Smith     SSmith@example.com    App 8
Finance Dept        213123    Ada Smith     ASmith@example.com    App 1
Finance Dept        213123    Ada Smith     ASmith@example.com    App 4
Finance Dept        213123    Ada Smith     ASmith@example.com    App 8
```

I added a pivot table, and organized the data to look like this:

```
Group               ID        Name          Email                 Access
Accounting Dept     932014    Betty Smith   BSmith@example.com    APP 1
                                                                  APP 2
                                                                  APP 3
                    321312    Ryan Smith    RSmith@example.com    APP 1 
                                                                  APP 2
                                                                  APP 3
                    543534    John Smith    JSmith@example.com    APP 1
                                                                  APP 2
                                                                  APP 3
Finance Dept        473924    Sam Smith     SSmith@example.com    APP 1
                                                                  APP 4
                                                                  APP 8 
                    213123    Ada Smith     ASmith@example.com    APP 1
                                                                  APP 4
                                                                  APP 8
```

How do I go about consolidating the "Access" column so it doesn't repeat the APP access? Is this even possible?

I would like the final data to look as such:

```
Group               ID        Name          Email                 Access
Accounting Dept     932014    Betty Smith   BSmith@example.com    APP 1
                                                                  APP 2
                                                                  APP 3
                    321312    Ryan Smith    RSmith@example.com    
                    543534    John Smith    JSmith@example.com  
Finance Dept        473924    Sam Smith     SSmith@example.com    APP 1
                                                                  APP 4
                                                                  APP 8 
                    213123    Ada Smith     ASmith@example.com
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how want the end result to look?

Comment: Hi @VitaliKaspler, I updated my post to show a final end result. I know its an odd request, but will your solution work for that output? I'd ideally might move the "Access" column to inbetween the "Group" and "ID" so format it a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Access` dimension from your table - this will automatically reduce the number of shown rows - will show only unique (Distinct) values.

If you want to combine the values of this dimension into a single value - you will need to tweak the underlying data source. For example, in the case of a spreadsheet - it would mean to create a new column with a formula (conditional concatenation or join). In SQL - you could use STRING_AGG or GROUP_CONCAT function (depending on the SQL syntax of your DB) with a GROUP BY.